# ELMAH - Filtering 404 Errors

Tags: asp.net, filtering, elmah

I am attempting to configure ELMAH to filter 404 errors and I am running into difficulties with the XML-provided filter rules in my Web.config file. I followed the tutorial [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/errorloggingmodulesandhandlers.aspx) and [here](http://www.matheda.com/Blog/Details/3/Exception-Logging-with-ELMAH) and added an `<is-type binding="BaseException" type="System.IO.FileNotFoundException" />` declaration under my `<test><or>...` declaration, but that completely failed.

When I tested it locally I stuck a breakpoint in `void ErrorLog_Filtering() {}` of the Global.asax and found that the `System.Web.HttpException` that gets fired by ASP.NET for a 404 doesn't seem to have a base type of `System.IO.FileNotFound`, but rather it is simply a `System.Web.HttpException`. I tested this by calling `e.Exception.GetBaseException().GetType()` in the event handler.

Next I decided to try a `<regex binding="BaseException.Message" pattern="The file '/[^']+' does not exist" />` in the hopes that any exception message matching the pattern "The file '/foo.ext' does not exist" would get filtered, but that too is having no effect. As a last resort I tried `<is-type binding="BaseException" type="System.Exception" />`, and even that is entirely disregarded.

I'm inclined to think there's a configuration error with ELMAH, but I fail to see any. Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Here's the relevant stuff from my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <elmah>
    <errorFilter>
      <test>
        <or>
          <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
          <regex binding="BaseException.Message" pattern="The file '/[^']+' does not exist" />
        </or>
      </test>
    </errorFilter>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/logs/elmah" />
  </elmah>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: that 2nd link throws a 404. Oh the Irony...

Comment: @Baldy Unfortunately, that is a new development. You can refer to my config sample for what you need.

Comment: its fine Nathan, the topic was helpful. i just found it funny that the topic is about 404s, and one of the links on the page leads to a 404 :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It was indeed a configuration error, just not one that was particularly obvious.

The order in which the ELMAH HttpModules are registered is a pertinent concern because in order for ELMAH to filter the exception it must first know which modules will be consuming the exception. **The ErrorFilter HttpModule must be registered last** to prevent the other modules from processing the exception being filtered. This seems [kind of] backwards to me, but at least it works.

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

---

After reviewing the [ELMAH Wiki entry on ErrorFiltering](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering#Filtering_Declaratively_via_Configuration) again I discovered this little tidbit of information <strike>which really deserves a **<strong />** tag, if you ask me</strike>. (**Edit**: They've bolded it since I first answered this question; props!)

> The first step is to configure an additional module called Elmah.ErrorFilterModule. Make sure you add it after any of the logging modules from ELMAH, as shown here with ErrorLogModule: