# Elmah ignoring ErrorFilter

Tags: web-config, elmah

I am trying to have elmah ignore 404 errors but they keep showing up. I am using asp.net mvc 3.

I have

```
  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
      <errorFilter>
          <test>
              <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
          </test>
      </errorFilter>
      <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
  </elmah>

   <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
```

Am I missing something? I used nuget to generate the web.config so I would think everything is in the web.config.

Comment: Possibly an issue with module order like in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854196/elmah-filtering-404-errors

Comment: @bronsoja - That post lead me to the correct answer. Apparently for whatever reason I was missing ErrorFilterin the "httpModules" and "modules". If you write you post as an answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly an issue with module order like in this post?

[ELMAH - Filtering 404 Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854196/elmah-filtering-404-errors)